# Unable to send mail in android emulator

Tags: android, email, android-emulator, smtp

I want to send mail automatically from my android app, so I configured the gmail account in my emulator and used the following code:

```
Intent emailIntentt = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntentt.setType("plain/text");  
String aEmailList[] = { "xxxx@gmail.com" };  
emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList); 
emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");   
emailIntentt.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello");
startActivityForResult(emailIntentt, 1);
```

But, it says no app found to send mail.

Also, while configuring email, I am unable to sync with the mail account from emulator. Does this cause the problem?

Comment: did you succeed to set up a google account on the emulator?

Comment: yes i successfully sign into existing email account.

Comment: but did you have the gmail application ?

Comment: i went to settings and went to add account to add the gmail account.is it right?

Comment: correct. But also You have to install the Gmail application fromo google play

Comment: but how to add email app in emulator?

Answer (score 0):

First, the MIME type of plain text is `text/plain`, not `plain/text`.

Second, as the comments indicate, you need an email app configured with an email account to be able to send email messages via `ACTION_SEND`.